# Dynamic desired page title using web forms and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, web

I have a textbox in which the user can enter their desired page title and save it. Once they save it and they happen to refresh the website, the web site title should be populated with the last title information they saved to display and the user will still have the ability to change it and re-save.  I am using web forms : pls how can i get this done .Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  How is that attempt not working?  It sounds like what you're asking is, "How do I write an ASP.NET application that uses a database?"  That's a bit broad and high-level, and there are many tutorials out there to help with this.  If you have made an attempt and are trying to figure out why it's not working, please share that attempt and we'll be happy to help resolve a specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use !ISPostBack

for see below code

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   {    
    if (!IsPostBack)
       {

       Page.Title = YourTextBox.Text;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the title to be persisted for all time, you have to store it in a db and dynamically set the title when the page loads. 
If you only need it for the remainder of the session, you may store it in session state.

I am leaving the full implementation as an exercise for the reader -- as it's too much to cover in this answer
 :-)